# Aura component not available in App Builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, lightning-apps, builder, packagelicense

I have an aura component in a managed package. The component has below configuration

```
<aura:component
  implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens"
  controller="XXController"
  access="global"
>
```

This aura component is visible in all org, except for one org. I have checked the license, permissions, and package version. Everything seems to be fine.

**Note: The aura component is available in Setup -> Lightning Components**

What could be the issue here?

Thanks in advance!